# Replacing a word in a text file

Tags: python, text-files

does anyone know how to replace a word in a text file?

Here's one line from my stock file:

```
bread 0.99 12135479 300 200 400
```

I want to be able to replace my 4th word (in this instance '300') when I print 'productline' with a new number created by the nstock part of this code:

```
for line in details: #for every line in the file:
        if digits in line: #if the barcode is in the line 
            productline=line #it stores the line as 'productline'
            itemsplit=productline.split(' ') #seperates into different words
            price=float(itemsplit[1]) #the price is the second part of the line
            current=int(itemsplit[3]) #the current stock level is the third part of the line
            quantity=int(input("How much of the product do you wish to purchase?\n"))
            if quantity<current:
                total=(price)*(quantity) #this works out the price
                print("Your total spent on this product is:\n" + "£" +str(total)+"\n") #this tells the user, in total how much they have spent
                with open("updatedstock.txt","w") as f:
                    f.writelines(productline) #writes the line with the product in
                    nstock=int(current-quantity) #the new stock level is the current level minus the quantity
```

My code does not replace the 4th word (which is the current stock level) with the new stock level (nstock)

Comment: So what problem or error are you experiencing? You should mention that rather than ask us to run the code to find out.

Comment: Just assign to the correct element in `itemsplit` then `' '.join(itemsplit)` to crete the new line.

Comment: I've edited my question to show that problem

Comment: It still doesn't replace anything

Comment: productline is never being changed. So of course your file wont change. maybe do this itemsplit[3] = quantity; f.writelines(' '.join(itemsplit)). I just realized is the same comment as @cdarke

Comment: I get an error message:                                                                    
TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, int found

Comment: use ' '.join([str(x) for x in itemsplit])

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use regular expressions for that purpose.

```
import re
string1='bread 0.99 12135479 300 200 400'
pattern='300'
to_replace_with="youyou"
string2=re.sub(pattern, to_replace_with, string1)
```

You will have the output bellow: 
     'bread 0.99 12135479 youyou 200 400'

Hope this was what you were looking for ;)

Comment: Thank you, will this work by me swapping the "youyou" with (nstock)?

Comment: Yes of course, but you got to put it between quotes, so it is considered as a string